# TL 2023 fontspec fatal error

Tags: fontspec, latex3

I am running a current and fully updated version of `TexLive 2023`. All of a sudden, none of my files would compile. I have tracked this down to an issue with `fontspec`. A minimal working (well: failing, really) example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}
```

This is an excerpt from the error log:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)  (format=lualatex 2023.10.26)  

L3 programming layer <2023-10-23>

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2023-11-01 L3 programming layer (loader) 

/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty:78: LaTeX Error
: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX)        Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX)        
(LaTeX)        The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX)        is dated 2023-10-23, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX)        at least 2023-11-01.

/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty:78:  
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Am I correct to assume that this is a programming error? Anything I can do for now?

Comment: you are missing an update you should have `L3 programming layer <2023-11-01>
`

Comment: or rather you are missing a format rebuild from the expl3 you have, try `fmtutil-sys --all`

Comment: I am running `tlmgr update --all` nightly and just ran it manually again: `tlmgr: no updates available`. EDIT: Will do.

Comment: you have the update but the format has not rebuilt for some reason. as the error shows your format has an older expl3 than the expl3.sty you have, see this for the log you should get https://texlive.net/run?%25!tex%20log%0A%5Cdocumentclass%7Barticle%7D%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bfontspec%7D%0A%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0ALorem%20ipsum.%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D

Comment: this comes up from time to time but never been clear why sometimes the formats do not get rebuilt, if you can debug why we would be interested, perhaps tlmgr could catch this better if we knew why it happened

Comment: Thank you very much, rebuilding the formats solved the issue.

Comment: yes that's the problem, it gets reported that fixes it then we never really know why it fails to build for some people some of the time

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see a pattern here, either. My updates are run by a cronjob, and this is the first time I've had this issue. Haven't done anyting differently.

Comment: yes that;s what everyone says, which makes it hard to debug, ok thanks anyway, if it happens again please do report it, although running fmtutil-sys will probably fix it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
L3 programming layer <2023-10-23>

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2023-11-01 L3 programming layer (loader)
```

shows that you have version `2023-11-01` of expl3 installed but your format is built with the older `2023-10-23`.

That should not happen as `tlmgr` is set up to rebuild the latex formats if any of the latex sources, including `expl3`, are updated. But occasionally it happens anyway for reasons that are not entirely clear.

Rebuilding the formats (`fmtutil-sys --all` (or perhaps `sudo fmtutil-sys --all`, depending on your installation choices) should rebuild the formats and avoid the error.